# Ubuntu fan noise while watching videos

Tags: nvidia, graphics, video, fan, sensors

While watching videos on either YouTube or anywhere else, on Ubuntu 22.04 creates high CPU utilization and fan noise. What's the reason? Is this okay and how do I avoid it?

My Windows dual booted with Ubuntu, never faced such thing on Windows.

GRAPHICS : NVIDIA CORPORATION GK208B[GeForce GT 730]

[image]

[image]

Normally the sensors used to be around 40 to 45 deg C.

Good to mention: When I first downloaded Ubuntu I accidentally downloaded xorg when nvidia driver was installed. Then uninstalled xorg and auto/reinstalled nvidia (if that created some problem).

not able to install psensor:
[image]

result when doing this way `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jfi/ppa`:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Disable CPU onboard graphics in the BIOS if you have any. It's called Intel UHD for Intel and I think AMD Radeon for AMD. Then run `lspci -v`. For your graphics card it must say `Kernel driver in use: nvidia`.

Comment: Is this a laptop, desktop or what? When last did you dust it out? Possibly the thermal paste has degraded.

Comment: Have you done `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The high CPU load of 90% is misleading. It is really 90% divided by the number of virtual CPU cores. In your case, 12 CPUs, it would be 7.5% CPU load.

You are using Google Chrome for YouTube videos and I found that makes my fans kick in as well. If I use Firefox to watch YouTube videos, then the fans stay off, or at least spin so slow, I can't hear them.

Comment: yep! it works fine in firefox , what's the reason it doesn't in chrome

Comment: @NarendraPal Chrome tends to have more "bleeding-edge" features. I imagine this comes with a penalty of more system overhead. You can try turning off new features / experimental features in Chrome. I use Firefiox all the time and only use Chrome for background testing so it's not important enough to investigate Chrome.

Comment: chrome only use 90% CPU when using you tube otherwise it's not .In firefox using youtube does not causes fan noise but it uses around 40-50 % CPU utilization when using you tube is that okay?

Comment: @NarendraPal Sounds about right. Mine is using 7% on 8 virtual cores which is 56% CPU in your language. You have 12 virtual cores so it's 50% / 12 = 5% CPU usage in my language which sounds correct because my CPU is older i-7.